# NSVisualEffectBlendingMode OS X Swift

Tags: swift, macos, window

I want to be able to make the background of my application blurry so you can almost see through the window like this

[image]

rather than the standard window

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: People here will help you if you are a few steps away from achieving your goal.  If you have done something, show us what you have done so far.  Otherwise, you should go to Make a Wish Foundation's web site or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found out the answer I was looking for and thought this might be useful for other people look for something similar. Heres my code :

```
import Cocoa

class window: NSWindowController {

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()

    let view = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1500, height: 800))
    view.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectBlendingMode.BehindWindow
    view.material = NSVisualEffectMaterial.Dark
    view.state = NSVisualEffectState.Active
    self.window!.contentView!.addSubview(view)

}

}
```

I made a NSWindowController class and added the code above to it. Then connected the class to the window controller in my main.storyboard.